# OpenCv subtract same image but from different sources

Tags: image, opencv, computer-vision, subtraction

I need to subtract two images:

1. img1 is original image act as object[Object Image (img1)](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0IUdCi6RzGcd1RxSjJlOTZRdUk&authuser=0)
2. img2 is clicked using camera act as scene[Scene Image (img2)](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0IUdCi6RzGcRzdnZjB0Y01SNUk&authuser=0)
3. Result Image: drive.google.com/open?id=0B0IUdCi6RzGcRENDSEdoa3dRN2c&authuser=0
   (I cannot add more than two links)

Before calling subtract method following steps are performed:

1. object image (img1) is located in scene image (img2) using `findHomography`   and `perspectiveTransform` methods.
2. Fix perspective using `getPerspectiveTransform` and `warpPerspective` methods

then `subtract` method is called but the output image contains lines/contours which should have been subtracted.

As per my observation this might be due to noise present in one image, it does not appear to be as sharp as img1, I tried calling subtract after sharpening it but it did not work.

Any suggestion/guidance is appriciated

Comment: can you post a sample result image? and sample imput images with perspective effects

Comment: Input image links are there in the question as I can only add two links as of now, here is the link for result image: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0IUdCi6RzGcRENDSEdoa3dRN2c&authuser=0

Comment: are those photo images? looked like template imagw and modified template image. sorry.

Comment: looks like the alignment isnt good enough and/or sharpness. My suggest: use binary images (threshold) an dilate the template image before subtracting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove unsharpness artifacts and slightly imperfect alignment issues, you can try to just dilate the template image. You'll lose some input information though.

If you want to do it "better", I would suggest you to to try find each contour of the template image in the input image (e.g. with active contours). Everything that remains, should be a user input.

But here the simple version with dilation:

Input:

input mask image:

[image]

template mask image after dilation:

[image]

difference image: `input - template`

[image]

please mind that I dont use any perspective correction, which might or might not improve the results!

```
int main()
{
    // edited image:
    cv::Mat input = cv::imread("../inputData/earth-science-worksheet-edited.png");
    cv::Mat grayInput;
    cv::cvtColor(input,grayInput,CV_BGR2GRAY);
    cv::Mat maskInput = grayInput < 150; // find everything that isn't "white" on your sheet of paper


    // template image:
    cv::Mat templateImage = cv::imread("../inputData/earth-science-worksheet-printable.png");
    cv::Mat grayTemplate;
    cv::cvtColor(templateImage,grayTemplate,CV_BGR2GRAY);
    cv::Mat maskTemplate = grayTemplate < 150; // find everything that isn't "white" on your sheet of paper

    // dilate the template image to overcome sharpness effects and imperfect alignment
    cv::dilate(maskTemplate, maskTemplate, cv::Mat(), cv::Point(-1,-1),1);

    // compute the difference image
    cv::Mat difference = maskInput - maskTemplate;


    cv::imshow("input", input);

    cv::imshow("mask template", maskTemplate);
    cv::imshow("mask input", maskInput);

    cv::imshow("difference", difference);

    cv::waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

if changed to `cv::dilate(maskTemplate, maskTemplate, cv::Mat(), cv::Point(-1,-1),2);` you lose a little more of the "input", but you remove the other noise pixel.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did try this in C++ and its working great but i will be writing my app in Java and I have a query: cv::Mat maskTemplate = grayTemplate < 150; // find everything that isn't "white" implies create empty Mat and iterate all Mat entries of grayTemplate and copy entry from grayTemplate to maskTemplate if entry value is less than 150. Am I correct.

Comment: no, it will create a new image with the same size as `grayTemplate` and sets every pixel to `255` that was smaller than 150 in `grayTemplate (all other pixel to 0). This is some kind of simple thresholding to find your black lines (contours and user input) in the original image (since your background = paper is white). So the value isn't copied but set to either 0 or 255.

Comment: Please tell me what "grayTemplate < 150" is called as, so I can search for it in opencv Java API

Comment: it is `compare` http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#matrix-expressions but I don't know the int value of `cmpop` you'll have to use for the java call... are the operators really not overloaded in java API?

Comment: you could instead use `cv::threshold` btw, if you choose the right parameters. This might give you some adaptiveness, too.

Comment: It is working in java also. There is compare method in Core class. Thank you Micka. Do we have to calibrate 150 value or it will always work?

Comment: you probably have to calibrate it. If the used pen is "less black" or the paper is "less white" or the lighting differs, the threshold might change. You could give Otsu thresholding a chance. But always keep in mind, that you want the dark objects (contours) to become foreground (== white in the mask) and the bright objects (paper) to become background (== black in the mask).